# Update about 1 million rows in MySQL table every 1 hour

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use Codeigniter 3.1.11 and have a question. I need to update about 1 million (in future will be much more) rows in MySQL table every 1 hour by Cron. But problem is if I update more than about 200-300 rows using this code, my server CPU is 100% loaded and table is stopping update after about 200-300 rows. And I even have to restart the PHP on my server to get the server back to normal.

What I do wrong?

How to do this task correctly, so that the query to the database is executed quickly and there is no heavy load on the server.

This is the code from controller:

```php
function cron_rows_update() {
$this->members_model->rows_update();
}
```

This is the code from model:

```php
function rows_update() {
   $currency_numbers_after_dot = $this->currencies_model->get_currency('ONE', 'My currencty')['numbers_after_dot'];
   $game_currency_percentage_max = $this->settings_model->get_settings_details('game_rating_percentage_max')['value'];
   $game_currency_speed_in_hour = $this->settings_model->get_settings_details('game_currency_speed_in_hour')['value'];
   $this->db->from('members');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $game_total_balance = round($row['game_vault_balance'] + $row['game_available_balance'], $currency_numbers_after_dot);

        // Game Rating Calculate
        // Rating Part1
        // Rating Part1_1
        if ($row['game_vault_balance'] == '0') {
            $rating_part1_1 = '0'; 
        }
        if ($row['game_vault_balance'] > '0' AND $row['game_vault_balance'] < '20') {
            $rating_part1_1 = '0.1'; 
        }
        if ($row['game_vault_balance'] > '20' 
            AND $row['game_vault_balance'] < '2000') {
        
            $max_game_vault_balance = '2000';
            $percent = floor($row['game_vault_balance'] * 100 / $max_game_vault_balance);
            $additional_rating = '0.05' * $percent / 100;
               
            $rating_part1_1 = round('0.1' + $additional_rating, 2); 
    
        }
        if ($row['game_vault_balance'] >= '2000') {
            $rating_part1_1 = '0.15'; 
        }
   
        // Rating Part1_2
        if ($game_total_balance == '0') {
            $PER_part1_2 = '0'; 
        }
        if ($game_total_balance > '0' AND $game_total_balance < '20') {
            $rating_part1_2 = '0.1'; 
        }
        if ($game_total_balance > '20' AND $game_total_balance < '2000') {
            $max_game_total_balance = '2000';
            $percent = floor($game_total_balance * 100 / $max_game_total_balance);
            $additional_rating = '0.05' * $percent / 100;
            $rating_part1_2 = round('0.1' + $additional_rating, 2); 
        }
        if ($game_total_balance >= '2000') {
            $rating_part1_2 = '0.15';
        }
        // Rating part1_3
        $rating_part1_3 = '0';
        // Rating part1_4
        $PER_part1_4 = '0';
        // Rating part2
        $PER_part2 = '0';
        // Rating part3
        $PER_part3 = '0';
        // Calculate all rating
        $rating = round($rating_part1_1 + $rating_part1_2 + $rating_part1_3 + $rating_part1_4 + $rating_part2 + $rating_part3, 2);
   
        if ($rating <= '1') {
            $rating_member = $rating;
        }
        if ($rating > '1') {
            $rating_member = floor($rating);
        }
        // Game balance calculate
        $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour = $game_currency_speed_in_hour / '100' * $row['game_vault_balance'];
        $new_balance_in_hour = ($game_currency_percentage_max / '100') * $row['rating'] * $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour;
        $game_balance_in_hour_amount = $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour + $new_balance_in_hour;

        // Update row in members table

        if ($game_total_balance > '0') {
            $this->db->where("UserID", $row['UserID']);
            $this->db->set("game_vault_balance", "game_vault_balance - " . $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour, FALSE);
            $this->db->set("game_available_balance", "game_available_balance + " . $game_balance_in_hour_amount, FALSE);
            $this->db->set("rating", $rating_member, FALSE);
            $this->db->set("game_rating_and_balance_update_last_time", 'NOW()', FALSE);
            $this->db->update("members");
        }
    } 
}
return;    
}
```

Comment: If the server gets down on 200 or 300 queries then you should either increase `server` capacity or the number of queries.

Comment: Check your server error log. Share your server config, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @BasheerKharoti I tried to scale my server to 32GB RAM and 8 CPU's and result was the same. I think may be I should not use foreach and need to something other method which will be much little to load my server?

Comment: Use shuf maybe?

Comment: @Hack5 What you means? Where to use shuf?

Comment: @Oleg Why don't you try `batch update` rather?

Comment: Is there any good reason to wrap numbers in quotes? Additionally, have you checked whether you could run the whole algoithm purely in SQL using `UPDATE` queries containing all formulas?

Comment: It would help to see your table definition (with index and foreign key definitions)... a `show create table tablename` would produce that. You may be experiencing a poor write performance because of index table rebuilding depending on that and what fields you're updating. Also, a `batch update` may help as you'd be performing a reduced number of `update` statements with bigger chunks of data, which tends to be faster and more efficient

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Thanks! Can you write an example of batch update instead of foreach in my case? And how do you think, is this SQL query will be faster if I make all calculations in SQL query instead of making it in php?

Comment: I really think your bottleneck is the database, not the application. Given the cardinality of your table, my instinct blames the table indexes unless proven otherwise. Can you share your table definition? Codeigniter's `update_batch` is pretty much the same as the regular `update`. You'd still need to loop through the data, build an array and then push it to the database. Check [THIS](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) and skip to the `$this->db->update_batch()` section

Comment: @oleg          Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your code is a little bit confusing (`$PER_part2` and `$PER_part3` are unused) i would do the following:

The script will not work with `result_array` for more than 1 million iterations.
The reason is, `result_array` stores all data in an array - and sooner or later you'll get a memory limit problem.

In order to avoid this you have to use `unbuffered_row`.
This method returns a single result row without prefetching the whole result in memory.

> Take a look at their documentation [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=unbuffered_row#result-rows). (section unbuffered_row)

The next thing i would change are your if blocks - i would use the `if/else` syntax here. (it isn't that big of a difference but considering your amount of rows - it might helps)

Also, i outsourced the block where you calculate your rating twice with the same logic behind.

Basically the following should work:

```
function rows_update() 
{
    $currency_numbers_after_dot = $this->currencies_model->get_currency('ONE', 'My currencty')['numbers_after_dot'];
    $game_currency_percentage_max = $this->settings_model->get_settings_details('game_rating_percentage_max')['value'];
    $game_currency_speed_in_hour = $this->settings_model->get_settings_details('game_currency_speed_in_hour')['value'];
    $this->db->from('members');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    
    $arrUpdateBatchData = [];
    
    while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array'))
    {
        $game_total_balance = round($row['game_vault_balance'] + $row['game_available_balance'], $currency_numbers_after_dot);
        if ($game_total_balance > 0) {
            // Game Rating Calculate
            // Rating Part1
            // Rating Part1_1
            $rating_part1_1 = $this->getRatingPart($row['game_vault_balance']);
            $rating_part1_2 = $this->getRatingPart($game_total_balance);
            // Rating part1_3
            $rating_part1_3 = 0;
            // Rating part1_4
            $rating_part1_4 = 0;
            // Rating part2
            $PER_part2 = '0';
            // Rating part3
            $PER_part3 = '0';
            // Calculate all rating
            $rating = round($rating_part1_1 + $rating_part1_2 + $rating_part1_3 + $rating_part1_4 + $rating_part2 + $rating_part3, 2);
            if ($rating <= 1) {
                $rating_member = $rating;
            }
            elseif ($rating > 1) {
                $rating_member = floor($rating);
            }
            
            // Game balance calculate
            $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour = $game_currency_speed_in_hour / '100' * $row['game_vault_balance'];
            $new_balance_in_hour = ($game_currency_percentage_max / '100') * $row['rating'] * $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour;
            $game_balance_in_hour_amount = $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour + $new_balance_in_hour;
            
            $arrUpdateData = [
                'UserID' => $row['UserID'], 
                'game_vault_balance' => ($row['game_vault_balance'] - $amount_from_game_vault_in_hour),
                'game_available_balance' => ($row['game_available_balance'] - $game_balance_in_hour_amount),
                'rating' => $rating_member,
                'game_rating_and_balance_update_last_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ];
            
            $arrUpdateBatchData[] = $arrUpdateData;
            
        }
        
        if (count($arrUpdateBatchData) > 500)
        {
            $this->db->update_batch('members', $arrUpdateBatchData, 'UserID');
            $arrUpdateBatchData = [];
        }       
    }
    
    //update last items
    if (count($arrUpdateBatchData) > 0)
    {
        $this->db->update_batch('members', $arrUpdateBatchData, 'UserID');
        $arrUpdateBatchData = [];
    }
    return;    
}

function getRatingPart($val)
{
    if ($val == 0) {
        $rating_part = 0; 
    }
    elseif ($val > 0 AND $val < 20) 
    {
        $rating_part = '0.1'; 
    }
    elseif ($val > 20 AND $val < 2000) 
    {
    
        $max_game_vault_balance = 2000;
        $percent = floor($val * 100 / $max_game_vault_balance);
        $additional_rating = 0.05 * $percent / 100;
           
        $rating_part = round(0.1 + $additional_rating, 2); 

    }
    else {
        $rating_part = 0.15; 
    }
    
    return $rating_part;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a good idea to use `update_batch`. Now it is updating 37000 rows for 9 seconds. But how can I use indexes in this query for reduce request time? Can I use for example `$this->db->update_batch('members use index (UserID) ', $arrUpdateBatchData, 'UserID');`?

Comment: I think you should open another question for that. The SQL query including the create query is necessary for this.

Answer (score 2):

Trying limitting the update instead of updating all at once. Update in chunks.

```
function cron_rows_update() {
   $num_of_members = $this->members_model->get_num_of_members();
   $limit_per_run = 150;
   $total_run = (int)$num_of_members/$per_run;
   
   for( $i = 0; $i <= $total_run; $i++ ) {
      $offset = $i * $limit_per_run;
      $this->members_model->rows_update($offset, $limit_per_run);
   }

}
```

and in `rows_update()`

```
function rows_update($offset, $limit_per_run) {
    
    **

    $this->db->limit($offset, $limit_per_run);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    
    $arrUpdateBatchData = [];
    
    while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array'))
    {
        // calculations and create array for batch update
    }

    // update in batch limiting to selected number of records
    if (count($arrUpdateBatchData) > 0)
    {
        $this->db->update_batch('members', $arrUpdateBatchData, 'UserID');
    }
}
```

You can also try using a timer function in controller to trigger update after a certain interval of time and increase the server capacities as mentioned in comments.

Read more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119621/how-to-update-10-million-rows-in-mysql-single-table-as-fast-as-possible) for further notes on high number of record updates as fast as possile and to decrease the load on server.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and write about the result. But do you think this is a temporary solution or might it work well with more than 1 million rows in 'members' table? Or I need to search other method than 'foreach'?

Comment: I think you should optimize from all sides.. optimized code (php logic and sql queries) , database configuration and server configuration for the future run, where you have to update thousands of records for faster execution and low load on server

Comment: Thank's. How do you think, should I add indexes on table columns in this case and what indexes should be added?

Comment: And should I use indexes in MySQL in my case if I use foreach($query->result_array() as $row) in my code?

Comment: Primary Keys and Foreign Keys will be automatically indexed which is good while searching using ID's.. while when searching in a large db for any other field other than ID's, Indexing that field would greatly improve fetching data.. `$this->db->get()` returns the result on which you are performing other operations. `foreach()` will not matter after the result has been returned.

Comment: @Oleg use `unbuffered_row()` with this mentioned by @sintakonte and try. Here, the number of records will be limited and hence that number of records will only be updated in batch.